# Multiple Prompts for Credentials

Tags: internet-explorer, login

I know there are multiple posts about this and I have tried all fixes with no luck.

When users go to sharepoint they are prompted for credentials 3 times. If they enter their credentials they are able to hit the site fine. If they hit cancel all 3 times they still get to the site.

Now here is the weirdest part. If a user hits one of the WFE's directly they are not prompted for credentials. They can immediately try to go to the main address for SP and they get prompted. Out layout is below.

I am at wits end on this and pulling my hair out. Nothing I try has worked. Any and all help is appreciated.

SP Layout

https://ozone.osumc.net - Main URL

Servers:
OZONE-SEARCH
OZONE-2
OZONE-3
OZONE-4
OZONE-SQL

This all worked fine with no issues as of last week. Over the weekend this started happening. No windows updates have been applied.

Comment: Is traffic being routed through a load balancer?

Comment: I would get Fiddler going and figure out what the HTTPS flow is (i.e. what server the request is pointing at). Regards..Antelope

Comment: We are going through a load balancer.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?